# Wrong Output. Largest and Smallest number is wrong?

Tags: python, output

Need help with an assignment. I'm not sure why I'm getting the largest and smallest number wrong.

```
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
      num = input('Enter a number: ')
      if num == 'done': 
        break
      try:
        y=float(num)
      except:
        print ('Invalid Input')
        continue
      if largest is None:
        largest=num
      elif num > largest:
        largest=num
      if smallest is None:
        smallest=num
      elif num < smallest:
        smallest=num
  
   print("Maximum is", largest)
   print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Please format the code, it's not readable like this.

Comment: WHat is your goal?

Comment: @BuddyBob I need to find the largest and smallest number that is entered in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

num is a string, the type needs to be converted when comparing

Answer (score 1):

You are converting float converted value and then storing it in `y`.
But you are comparing using `num`.
Try this:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input('Enter a number: ')
    try:
            y=float(num)
    except Exception as e:
            print ('Invalid Input')
            break
    if not largest:
            largest=y
    elif y > largest:
            largest=y
    if not smallest:
            smallest=y
    elif y < smallest:
            smallest=y
  
print("Maximum is", largest)
print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

This will break from the loop once you enter anything that cannot be parsed as a number in python.
**Also use this in python 3. If you're using python2.7, you need raw_input.**

> If you are using Python 3.x, raw_input has been renamed to input. Quoting the [Python 3.0 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) PEP3111,
>
> > raw_input() was renamed to input(). That is, the new input() function reads a line from sys.stdin and returns it with the trailing newline stripped. It raises EOFError if the input is terminated prematurely. To get the old behavior of input(), use eval(input())

Answer (score 0):

In your code, line 8, you define `y = float(num)`. Then you just need to use `y` instead of `num`, like this:

```
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
      num = input('Enter a number: ')
      if num == 'done': 
        break
      try:
        y=float(num)
      except:
        print ('Invalid Input')
        continue
      if largest is None:
        largest=y
      elif y > largest: # !!!
        largest=y
      if smallest is None:
        smallest=y
      elif y < smallest: # !!!
        smallest=y
  
   print("Maximum is", largest)
   print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, You have to change your cast in the try:

```
try:
    num=float(num)
except:
    print ('Invalid Input')
```